# My blur node does not affect a shadow between rendernodes

Tags: rendering, node-editor, render-layers

so I'm sort of new to blender. I've recently started to experiment with nodes and render layers. Currently, I'm trying to make one object (and the shadows cast by it) blurred. I've tried running the object through a blur filter node, but that doesn't appear to have done anything with the shadow on the other object (which is sort of cool because I can use it for focus and perspective trick, but isn't so convenient for me.)

How can I get both the object and it's shadows in other render layers to both be affected by this node?

[image]

Comment: That just blurs both the cube and the sphere. I'm just trying to blur the sphere and its shadow on the cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fake way to do it is increase the size of the light, a lot.

[image: fake: big light]

Another fake way to do it is by mixing a transparent node with your shader and use *facing* layer weight for factor

[image: fake2: transparent surface shader]

(sorry for self hosting, imgur declined my request)

And now the real way: volumetrics

[image: Real: volumetrics]

Plug a volume scatter shader to the volume output and control it's density with a spherical gradient. Probably can be modified for non spherical objects too.